# Editing a signature block

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to get a signature block that look exactly like what is shown below, but I am unable to achieve it in LaTeX. Can anybody be of help to me. Please note that the Jun 13 is left aligned, while the Offshore Ops is directly below the Deputy General.

```
                                                            AA ABCDEF
                                                            Deputy General
Jun 13                                                      Offshore Ops
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the construction on the right in a `tabular`, pushing it over to the right using an `\hfill`, making sure it's aligned at the `[b]`ottom:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\noindent \today \hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  AA ABCDEF \\
  Deputy General \\
  Offshore Ops
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

The text block boundary was added using [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to highlight the alignment of the components, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.